# Google Analytics Event Value shows in Google Tag Manager Preview but not sent in Production after publishing

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

I created a custom tag in google Tag Manager with an event value that is calculated in a javascript variable. In preview mode on my website, the tag fires with the correct event value.
When I publish the workspace in production, and check I can see the tag fires correctly but event value is always zero.

Preview mode

[image: Tag Manager Preview]

Production Console

[image: Event in Console]

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more information on how you are calculating `Event Value`. My guess is that it's some sort of race condition where your logic is trying to execute before the value becomes available in the DOM.

Try adding an artificial 2-3 second delay in your tag firing and see if you start collecting data in your PROD environment. If you are, it will confirm that race condition hypothesis.